# scraping web with vba, extract number e code color from bgcolor

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, nested-attributes

hello I would like to count how many bgcolor there are under the tag td and extract the color code from attribute "bgcolor"

```
<td bgcolor="#1ea8ec" style="color:#ffffff">2.</td>
```

Comment: What *exactly* is stopping you from doing that?  Please update with your existing code and a description of what problem(s) you're running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way.

1. Use xmlhttp to avoid opening browser
2. Use css selectors for faster retrieval
3. Use an id selector for table, not class name as this is the optimal selection method
4. Reduce looping by generating a nodeList with a single loop
5. Use a dictionary to ensure only unique values stored

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetColourCodes()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, dict As Object, i As Long, colourCodes As Object
    Set html = New HTMLDocument: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.soccer-rating.com/France/", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    Set colourCodes = html.querySelectorAll("#ltable td[bgcolor]")
    For i = 0 To colourCodes.Length - 1
        dict(colourCodes.item(i).bgColor) = vbNullString
    Next
    Stop '<=Delete me later
End Sub
```

---

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub rating()
Set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

Dim itemEle As Object
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "http://www.soccer-rating.com/France/"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set itemEle = objIE.document.getElementsByclassname("ltable")(0)
i = 0
For Each tr In itemEle.getElementsBytagname("tr")
    color = 
    j = 2
    For Each td In tr.getElementsBytagname("td")
    'if bgcolor there is then
          Sheets("rating").Cells(i, j).interior.color  = 'here color code of bgcolor "#1ea8ec"
     'end if
     j = j + 1
    Next td
    i = i + 1

Next tr
End Sub
```

if it finds bgcolor then it takes the code color and colors the cell

Comment: I solved with the command  **x = td.getAttribute ("bgcolor")**